# Why isn't $\mu$ differentiated here?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, vectors, calculus

McIntyre Quantum mechanics while describing Stern-Gerlach experiment

> The results of the experiment suggest an interaction between a neutral particle and a magnetic field. We expect such an interaction if the particle possesses a magnetic moment $\boldsymbol{\mu}$. The potential energy of this interaction is $E=-\mu \cdot \mathbf{B}$, which results in a force $\mathbf{F}=\nabla(\boldsymbol{\mu} \cdot \mathbf{B})$. In theStern-Gerlach experiment, the magnetic field gradient is primarily in the z-direction, and the resulting -component of the force is
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> F_{z} &=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(\boldsymbol{\mu} \cdot \mathbf{B}) \\
> & \cong\mu_{z} \frac{\partial B_{z}}{\partial z}
> \end{aligned}
> $$

Why wasn't $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ differentiated in $$
\begin{aligned}
F_{z} &=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(\boldsymbol{\mu} \cdot \mathbf{B}) \\
&  \cong    \mu_{z} \frac{\partial B_{z}}{\partial z}~?
\end{aligned}
$$
Won't $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ depend on $z$ as the particle travels through space?

Comment: The magnetc moment of the electron is a constant ${\boldsymbol \mu}= ge/2m_{\rm electron}{\bf S}$.

Comment: Thank you sir. It's the same about the atom? Also is the magnetic moment you wrote from classical electrodynamics?

Comment: No. Not classical. It's a quantum effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbf{F}=\nabla(\boldsymbol{\mu} \cdot \mathbf{B})$$

is a slightly facetious way of putting it. The electron's magnetic moment $\mu$ is a constant and independent from other quantities in the Stern-Gerlach experiment, so it's the same as writing:

$$F_z=\mu \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial z}$$

Comment: Thank you. In the stern gerlach we've atoms/molecules instead of electrons, does the atoms/molecules have a fixed magnetic moment vector? Also is this result i.e a fixed magnetic moment from classical electrodynamics?

Comment: Stern Gerlach uses silver atoms, which have a lone electron (look up the electron configuration of $\text{Ag}$) So each atom has a *net* MM, of one electron.